# Problem using wp_mail function

Tags: wp-mail

I have a form whose message is composed from multiple input fields when submitted. I got this form working as simple php document but when I'm trying to use the form within a wordpress page it doesn't work. And I've switched to wp_mail function. Anyone has any idea? Thank you

```
<?php
$errors = array();
$missing = array();

if (isset($_POST['send'])) {
    $to = 'mail@yahoo.com';
    $subject = 'Form';
    $expected = array('name', 'email', 'pick_up_adress', 'drop_off_adress', 'phone', 'pick_date', 'pick_time', 'type');
    $required = array('name', 'email', 'pick_up_adress', 'drop_off_adress', 'phone', 'pick_date', 'pick_time', 'type');
    $headers = "From: Metro<email@example.com>\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8';

    if ($mailSent) {
        header('Location: after_form.php');
        exit;
    }
}

// Array proccesing
$mailSent = false; 
if (!$suspect && !$missing && !$errors) {
    $message = '';

    foreach($expected as $item) {
        if (isset(${$item}) && !empty(${$item})) {
            $val = ${$item};
        } else {
            $val = 'Not selected';
        }

        if (is_array($val)) {
            $val = implode(', ', $val);
        }

        $item = str_replace(array('_', '-'), ' ', $item);
        $message .= ucfirst($item).": $val\r\n\r\n";
    }

    $message = wordwrap($message, 70);

    // simple php doc $mailSent = mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers); 
    $mailSent = wp_mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

    if (!$mailSent) {
        $errors['mailfail'] = true;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Where do you put this code?

Comment: In the page where the form is.

Comment: Is this code _before_ `get_header` in the page's template?

Comment: Yes, right at the top

Comment: What is the use of 1st `if` block? The `$mailSent` is not set there and you are trying to redirect? Also why you are checking for array here `if (is_array($val))`?

Comment: Read about [Debugging in WordPress](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress), then enable `WP_DEBUG` and `WP_DEBUG_LOG` and add some [error_log](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-log.php) statements to your code so that you can see what's going on. e.g. `error_log("POST:\n" . print_r($_POST,1));`

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of problems that may lead to failure of your script.

First, you have a check for `$mailSent` at the top so you can redirect. However, at that point, it is undefined.  It would be less likely to be a problem if you move it to where you check it at the end and set an error.  In fact, I would move all of that outside your `if (!$suspect && !$missing && !$errors) {` check.

And that brings up another similar problem. Where does `$suspect` come from? This appears to be undefined as well.  I'd take that out if it isn't supposed to be there.

Here are those changes:

```
$errors = array();
$missing = array();

if (isset($_POST['send'])) {
    $to = 'mail@yahoo.com';
    $subject = 'Form';
    $expected = array('name', 'email', 'pick_up_adress', 'drop_off_adress', 'phone', 'pick_date', 'pick_time', 'type');
    $required = array('name', 'email', 'pick_up_adress', 'drop_off_adress', 'phone', 'pick_date', 'pick_time', 'type');
    $headers = "From: Metro<email@example.com>\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8';
}

// Array proccesing
$mailSent = false; 
if (!$missing && !$errors) {
    $message = '';

    foreach($expected as $item) {
        if (isset(${$item}) && !empty(${$item})) {
            $val = ${$item};
        } else {
            $val = 'Not selected';
        }

        if (is_array($val)) {
            $val = implode(', ', $val);
        }

        $item = str_replace(array('_', '-'), ' ', $item);
        $message .= ucfirst($item).": $val\r\n\r\n";
    }

    $message = wordwrap($message, 70);

    // simple php doc $mailSent = mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers); 
    $mailSent = wp_mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
}

if ( $mailSent ) {
    header('Location: after_form.php');
    exit;
} else {
    $errors['mailfail'] = true;
}
```

Lastly, I would be inclined to put this in an action hook rather than in a template.  It can certainly work in a template, so that's up to you, but I think a hooked action such as `init` would be more portable.